# D3.js change x-axis path line style

Tags: svg, d3.js

In d3.js charts, the x-axis line (black line between the bars and bar labels) sort of looks like this by default: |----------------|, see screenshot below:

[image: Note the double line in the pink box. Very unsightly.]

How would I change this to just a straight line (no vertical lines on either end)?

Looking at the generated SVG, this code seems to be determining that style: `<path class="domain" d="M0,6V0H824V6"></path>`, which is auto-generated by D3.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `axis.outerTickSize(0)`?

Comment: That works! I read the docs on that but missed the meaning. If you want to turn your response into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is controlled by [`axis.outerTickSize()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#outerTickSize):

> An outer tick size of 0 suppresses the square ends of the domain path, instead producing a straight line.

All you need to do is set `axis.outerTickSize(0)`.

Answer (score 6):

Lars Kotthoff's answer is still valid for d3 versions prior to 4.x, with version 4 it changed to `axis.tickSizeOuter()`. Note that `tickSize()` modifies the outer ticks as well, which means the order of calling `tickSize()` and `tickSizeOuter()` is important.

```
d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickValues(series)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickSizeOuter(0)
);
```